# Image captured from camera is not displaying

Tags: java, android

I am trying to capture an image and then display it on the screen using another activity. I am able to successfully capture the images and save them in my desired directory. However, even after hours of struggle, I am still unable to solve this problem. The touch listener is added to the screen though there's no image. 
Here's the code:

```
private void takeImage(){ Intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());


File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdirs();

File image = new File(imagesFolder, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");
Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

startActivityForResult(imageIntent, PHOTO_TAKEN); }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_TAKEN){
       data.putExtra(SET_CAPTURED_IMAGE, true);
    } else{
       Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUGTAG, "Photo = null");
   }
}
```

Now in another activity (ImageActivity):

addTouchListener() is called in onCreate() method of this activity.
Till here, the image is successfully captured and saved in the directory.

```
private void addTouchListener(){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.unlocker_image);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

//The following if block is not executed
    if (extras != null && extras.getBoolean(MainActivity.SET_CAPTURED_IMAGE)){
        Uri imageUri= Uri.parse(extras.getString(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unlocker_image);
        //this is the default image added
   }
imageView.setOnTouchListener(collector);
}
```

At this point, the touch listener is added but there's no image.

Comment: `I am still unable to solve this problem.`. Which problem? Totatally unclear what goes ok and what goes wrong.

Comment: @greenapps The problem is that the image captured from the phone camera is not getting displayed on the screen.

Comment: Then where does it go wrong? You just dump a bunch of code and we should debug it? You have to tell what goes ok and where it goes wrong.

Comment: The first block of code runs perfectly fine. The second block doesn't work as intended. Please tell me is this the right way to get the uri using extras or am I missing something important here. 
I apologize if I wasn't clear enough before. It's only second time that I've posted a question on this site so I'm kind of a newbie to this.

Comment: @greenapps I have added a comment in the second block.

Comment: `Intent = new Intent(android` ??? Where and how is your second activity started? Why dont you show that?

Comment: `//The following if block is not executed`. Why not? There is an &&. Which one is not true? So R.drawable.unlocker_image is set? Why dont you tell hat happens?